# Scrolling in android LinearLayout using XML

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll

I have made a very simple collection of ImageButtons using XML in android, with the parent layout being LinearLayout with orientation set to vertical.
I read on that LinearLayout adds the scroll automatically if the height of the content exceeds the screen.

The link is: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

The introduction below the LinearLayout diagram says so.

But the problem is that content is not being displayed after the window's height and content is missing.
I am at my wit's end and have searched other's answered questions... I donot want to use a ListView, but if i have to, i'll do it.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code please so we can see what you are doing that might be causing your problem?

Comment: @0gravity thanks :) ... That solved it. enclosed the whole layout in it, and it did the trick